# AngularJS empty http requests

Tags: php, angularjs, windows, apache, xampp

I have recently switched to Windows10 from Ubuntu 17.04.
in Ubuntu I had the latest versions of Apache, PHP (PhalconPHP enabled).

in Windows 10 I have the latest version of XAMPP installed.

in Windows, all my websites have strange behaviour. for example in my angularJS website,
all $http requests return empty response with status: 200 (which means there is no error in my PHP code).
the strange thing is the same URLs return data when entered in browser URL input.

the apache error_log:

```
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:18.900931 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.027166 2018] [core:warn] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.044248 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.127479 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH00455: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.127479 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Nov  3 2017 10:30:36
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.127479 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.150227 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10808:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5908
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:19.934501 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5908:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:20.014506 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5908:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jan 19 11:25:20.071023 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5908:tid 668] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

the following is my http factory:

```
app.factory('network', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
var network = {};

network.request = function(addr, params, callback = "", failcallback = ""){
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: config.server + addr,
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: params
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        function(response) {
            if (failcallback){
                failcallback(response);
            }
    });
}

return network;
}]);
```

and the network factory can be called in controllers:

```
network.request("/some-action-url", {
       data
    }, function(response){
        if (response.data.status == "OK"){  
          // do something
        } else {
          // get error from server
        }
    });
```

I don't think there's a problem with my code, since it worked well on the Ubuntu I had. there might be something wrong with apache, php or windows settings.

Comment: What are request type of the request in the browser ? GET or OPTION ?

Comment: @TusharNikam I reinstalled ubuntu again. None of my websites worked correctly on windows 10. I think the problem was with windows settings maybe